# SpringBoot Data - How to delete all rows that share an id?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Lets say I have a table called "USER".  In this table, I have all the user data, and I assign the user a unique id and therefore each row is unique.

It looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq")
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "FRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    ... a lot more stuff ...

}
```

I also have another table where I assign all the roles the user has, which each row looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLES")
public class UserRoleMap {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    Long userId;

    @Column(name = "USER_ROLE_ID")
    Long userRoleId;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DATE")
    String updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
    String updatedBy;

}
```

This table has no explicit unique key.  The data could easily look like the following, where `12278` is the unique userId.

```
12,278  8,420   pretend_timestamp   admin_user
12,278  8,430   pretend_timestamp   admin_user
12,278  8,476   pretend_timestamp   admin_user
12,278  8,478   pretend_timestamp   admin_user
12,278  18,578  pretend_timestamp   admin_user
12,278  8,482   pretend_timestamp   admin_user
12,278  18,539  pretend_timestamp   admin_user
```

**So how do I do the following using idiomatic spring-boot?**

```
DELETE USER_ROLES where USER_ID = 12278
```

---

I have tried the following, but spring-boot throws an error:

```
userRoleRepository.deleteById(user.getUserId);
```

gives

```
org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update
```

Answer (score 3):

On your `UserRoleRepository` interface try the following: `void deleteAllByUserId(Long userId);` and then call this in your service logic.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge the design of your `UserRoleMap` Entity is wrong, since your are mentioning `userId` as the Id(that means primary key).Thus, it is always required that your `userId` should be **unique** for each row in `USER_ROLES` table(which is the feature of primary key).

According to me you might not be defining `userId` as primary key in your table scripts while creating table and you might have inserted data via insert queries into database and not via spring-data-jpa.

Now in your spring-data-jpa when you are trying to `deleteById` , it expects to find only one row and delete(because your mentioning `@Id` for `userId`) but since you have multiple rows in your table with the same `userId`, you are facing the above exception.

The best possible solution would be create a proper primary key in your `USER_ROLES` table (might be the composite primary key of `userId` and `roleId`)

or delete via HQL

`(delete from UserRoleMap  where userId =:userID)`.

But ideally while using ORM a unique primary key in your mapping table is quite necessary otherwise you may face more issues.

Comment: You are correct in your assessment on how the database tables were created.  I was not with this team when they created the tables.  HQL is probably my only option at this point